# Can I use a computed property to conditionally style a table row?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am rendering a table of users, and I would like the entire row to be highlighted for only the current user.

I think that the easiest way to do this would be through a computed property, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

In the code below in the comment is what I'm thinking, but it won't render. I only want the pink highlight on the current user 'nathan'.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentUser: 'nathan',
    users: [{
        name: "nathan",
        email: "nathan@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        name: "sally",
        email: "sally@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        name: "joe",
        email: "joe@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    styles: function(user) {
      let height = 100

      // something like this?
      // if(user === currentUser)
      if (user) {
        return {
          'background-color': 'pink'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="user in users">
      <td v-bind:style="styles">{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td v-bind:style="styles">{{ user.email }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a proper CSS class? Inline styles should *never* be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to a computed property, so it won't have the `user` parameter filled in.

You can create a class and add that to your row, depending on the condition you want.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentUser: 'nathan',
    users: [{
        name: "nathan",
        email: "nathan@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        name: "sally",
        email: "sally@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        name: "joe",
        email: "joe@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="user in users" :class="{'current-user' : user.name === currentUser}">
      <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<style>
  tr.current-user {
    background-color: pink;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! That is just what I needed :)